# Put Excel Loop in Stata

Tags: excel, loops, stata

I am trying to extract values incorporated in a Forvalues "Loop" from Stata to Excel.

```
forvalues i = 20(5)40 {

forvalues x = 0(5)10 {
local xlsrow = 2
putexcel A`xlsrow'=("`i'_`x'") using results, sheet("individuals") modify

local xlsrow = `xlsrow'+4               
}
}
```

In the first stage I just want to write the different combinations of the variables i & x into the column A. Unfortunately, the only result I receive is the last combination 40_10 in row A2. So somehow, I must have a problem in the local xlsrow, but I am unable to figure it out. Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you have in mind, but this will create data in cells in A2:A16 that look like this:

```
20_0
20_5
20_10
25_0
...
40_10
```

Stata code:

```
local xlsrow = 2
putexcel set results, sheet("individuals") replace

forvalues i = 20(5)40 {
    forvalues x = 0(5)10 {
        putexcel A`xlsrow'=("`i'_`x'")
        local xlsrow = `xlsrow'+1               
    }
}

!open results.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy! This absolutely solves my problem! Highly appreciated!

Comment: @Raphael Glad it helped. You can select it as the answer by clicking the ✔ on the left.